# Why the need to use the volatile keyword on global variables when handling interrupts in Arduino?

Tags: c++, interrupt, isr

I am familiar with the keyword `Volatile` being used to declare variables that are shared among multiple threads on a software application (basically on a multithreaded application).

But why do I need to declare a variable as `Volatile` when running the code on an an Arduino interrupt? Is the code running in the interrupt executing on different thread? Is there something else going on?

Comment: You have to tell the compiler that the variable exists so that optimization algorithms don't remove it entirely from your executable.

Comment: "I am familiar with the keyword Volatile". Then forget about it, and read again.

Comment: Effectively the interrupt handler is a separate thread from main. Without the volatile declaration, compiler does not know that main must re-read the global (which may have been changed by the interrupt handler).

Comment: `Is the code running in the interrupt executing on different thread` - well sort of, only the opposite. Interrupts are the mechanism, the technique used by OS programmers, to implement threads. So we need to use `volatile` in multithreaded code because their context has been switched by the OS in an interrupt. We need to use `volatile` in interrupts simply because interrupts run in a different context.

Answer (score 16):

First, it's `volatile` not `Volatile`. I cover these concepts in my page about [Interrupts](http://www.gammon.com.au/interrupts) however to avoid giving a link-only answer I'll repeat the relevant bits.

---

### What are "volatile" variables?

Variables **shared** between ISR functions and normal functions should be declared `volatile`. This tells the compiler that such variables might change at any time, and thus the compiler must reload the variable whenever you reference it, rather than relying upon a copy it might have in a processor register.

For example:

```
volatile boolean flag;

// Interrupt Service Routine (ISR)
void isr ()
{
 flag = true;
}  // end of isr

void setup ()
{
  attachInterrupt (0, isr, CHANGE);  // attach interrupt handler
}  // end of setup

void loop ()
{
  if (flag)
    {
    // interrupt has occurred
    }
}  // end of loop
```

---

### Critical sections ... accessing volatile variables

There are some subtle issues regarding variables which are shared between interrupt service routines (ISRs) and the main code (that is, the code not in an ISR).

Since an ISR can fire at any time when interrupts are enabled, you need to be cautious about accessing such shared variables, as they may be being updated at the very moment you access them.

---

#### First ... when do you use "volatile" variables?

A variable should only be marked volatile if it is used both inside an ISR, and outside one.

- Variables **only** used **outside** an ISR should **not** be volatile.
- Variables **only** used **inside** an ISR should **not** be volatile.
- Variables used both **inside and outside** an ISR **should be** volatile.

eg.

```
volatile int counter;
```

Marking a variable as volatile tells the compiler to not "cache" the variable's contents into a processor register, but always read it from memory, when needed. This may slow down processing, which is why you don't just make every variable volatile, when not needed.

---

#### Atomic access

Consider this code:

```
volatile byte count;

ISR (TIMER1_OVF_vect)
  {
  count = 10;
  }

void setup ()
  {
  }

void loop () 
  {
  count++;
  }
```

The code generated for `count++` (add 1 to count) is this:

```
 14c:   80 91 00 02     lds r24, 0x0200
 150:   8f 5f           subi    r24, 0xFF     <<---- problem if interrupt occurs before this is executed
 152:   80 93 00 02     sts 0x0200, r24   <<---- problem if interrupt occurs before this is executed
```

*(Note that it adds 1 by subtracting -1)*

There are two danger points here, as marked. If the interrupt fires after the lds (load register 24 with the variable `count`), but before the sts (store back into the variable `count`) then the variable might be changed by the ISR (TIMER1_OVF_vect), however **this change is now lost**, because the variable in the register was used instead.

We need to protect the shared variable by turning off interrupts briefly, like this:

```
volatile byte count;

ISR (TIMER1_OVF_vect)
  {
  count = 10;
  }  // end of TIMER1_OVF_vect

void setup ()
  {
  }  // end of setup

void loop () 
  {
  noInterrupts ();
  count++;
  interrupts ();
  } // end of loop
```

Now the update of `count` is done "atomically" ... that is, it cannot be interrupted.

---

#### Multi-byte variables

Let's make `count` a 2-byte variable, and see the other problem:

```
volatile unsigned int count;

ISR (TIMER1_OVF_vect)
  {
  count++;
  } // end of TIMER1_OVF_vect

void setup ()
  {
  pinMode (13, OUTPUT);
  }  // end of setup

void loop () 
  {
  if (count > 20)
     digitalWrite (13, HIGH);
  } // end of loop
```

OK, we are not changing `count` any more, so is there still a problem? Sadly, yes. Let's look at the generated code for the "if" statement:

```
 172:   80 91 10 02     lds r24, 0x0210
 176:   90 91 11 02     lds r25, 0x0211  <<---- problem if interrupt occurs before this is executed
 17a:   45 97           sbiw    r24, 0x15   
 17c:   50 f0           brcs    .+20
```

Imagine that `count` was 0xFFFF and was about to "wrap around" back to zero. We load 0xFF into one register, but before we load the second 0xFF the variable changes to 0x00. Now we think `count` is 0x00FF which is neither the value it had before (0xFFFF) or now (0x0000).

So again we have to "protect" the access to the shared variable, like this:

```
void loop () 
  {
  noInterrupts ();
  if (count > 20)
     digitalWrite (13, HIGH);
  interrupts ();
  }  // end of loop
```

---

#### What if you are not sure interrupts are on or off?

There is a final "gotcha" here. What if interrupts might be off already? Then turning them back on afterwards is a Bad Idea.

In that case you need to save the processor status register like this:

```
unsigned int getCount ()
  {
  unsigned int c;
  byte oldSREG = SREG;   // remember if interrupts are on or off

  noInterrupts ();   // turn interrupts off
  c = count;         // access the shared variable
  SREG = oldSREG;    // turn interrupts back on, if they were on before

  return c;          // return copy of shared variable
  }  // end of getCount
```

This "safe" code saves the current status of interrupts, turns them off (they may already be off), gets the shared variable into a temporary variable, turns interrupts back on - if they were on when we entered the function - and then returns the copy of the shared variable.

---

### Summary

Code may "appear to work" even if you don't take the above precautions. That is because the chances of the interrupt occurring at the exact wrong moment is fairly low (maybe 1 in 100, depending on the code size). But sooner or later it will happen at the wrong moment, and your code will either crash, or occasionally return the wrong results.

So for reliable code, pay attention to protecting access to shared variables.

Comment: I thought volatile would handle the multi-byte types read and write access in the main loop and ISR! 
So, I was completely wrong and should turn off the interrupts before accessing them in the main loop, right?! ;-(

Comment: That's right. `volatile` just tells the compiler to not optimize and keep variables in processor registers. It doesn't have any other side-effects (apart from letting the compiler know these variables may change at any time, so volatile variables are never optimized away because they "aren't used"). So yes, as illustrated above, "guard" access to multi-byte variables by turning interrupts off.

Comment: Is it safe to remove `volatile` if we use the final version of `getCount()`?

Comment: I don't understand why the line (sbiw r24, 0x15) uses the value 0x15 instead of the value 20 in the "Multi-byte variable" section. Could it be a mistake?

Comment: @ecc Well, one is hex and one is decimal. Of course, 0x15 is 21 in decimal, not 20. However the compiler may have decided to subtract 21 and check if the carry bit was set, instead of comparing to 20. This would be part of compiler optimization. In other words, > 20 is the same as >= 21.

Answer (score 7):

`volatile` has nothing to do with multithreading per se, and it seems to be among the most miused keywords in that area. It is never a substitute for proper synchronization.

As per standard C, `volatile` invokes mostly implementation defined behaviour of telling the compiler to not optimize away accesses to the memory a variable resides in, even if the compiler thinks there can't be any other.

This *can* be useful in the following situations where the compiler is not aware that outside means can change a variable:

- memory mapped hardware registers
- variables accessed from other threads but checked in a tight loop
- variables accessed from interrupt or signal handlers but checked in a tight loop