# How to pass input from a Midi controller to a function?

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, midi

I am trying to pass the `input[]`, `data1(pitch)` from a Midi controller to the `waitForButton` function. When a key is pressed it sends `data1(pitch)` into the array `input[]`, and when the key is up the array value goes to zero. But the input isn't being passed to the function as I am pressing the keys on the Midi controller. What am I missing?

```
void MyHandleNoteOn(byte channel, byte pitch, byte velocity) {
  data1 = MIDI.getData1();
  if (data1==48) { //C3
    Status[0][0]=1;
    noteOn(0,data1,100);
    input[0]=data1;
  }
}

void MyHandleNoteOff(byte channel, byte pitch, byte velocity) {
  data1 = MIDI.getData1();
  if (data1==48) { //C3
    Status[0][0]=0;
    noteOff(0,data1,100);
    input[0]=0;
  }
}

void readsequnce() {
  bool mademistake = false;
  int key;
  for (int index = 0; index < largestindex & mademistake == false; index++) {
    key = waitForButton(5000);
    if(key ==-1 || key != note[index]) {
      mademistake = true;
      state = 2;
    }
  }
}

int waitForButton(int laps) {
  int keyPressed= -1;
  int check;
  boolean keyBackUp = false;
  currentMillis = millis();
  // The number of ms since the program started running
  previousMillis = currentMillis;
  // Records the point when we start spinning the loop.
  // Keep spinning the loop until "delay" seconds have passed.
  while (currentMillis - previousMillis < laps & keyBackUp == false) {
    lcd.setCursor(16, 2);
    lcd.print(String(keyPressed));
    // Read the button and record when it has been pushed down.
    for (int i = 0; i < 25 & keyBackUp == false; i++) {
      if (input[i] != 0) {
        keyPressed = input[i];
        // Show the LED pushed.
        noteOn(0, keyPressed, 100);
        //  digitalWrite(leds[pin], HIGH);
        // It is possible the button is still being pushed.
        // This loop spins until the button is let up.
        while (currentMillis - previousMillis < laps & keyBackUp == false) {
          check = input[i];
          if (check == 0) {
            keyBackUp = true;
          }
          currentMillis = millis();
        }
        // Turn the LED pushed off.
        noteOff(0, keyPressed, 0);
        // digitalWrite(leds[pin], LOW);
        // See if they took to long.
        if (currentMillis - previousMillis > laps) {
          keyPressed = -1;
          // They took to long to let the button up so they lose.
        }
      }
    }
    currentMillis = millis();
  }
  return keyPressed;
}
```

Comment: the change of the array is shown in the  MyHandleNoteOff and  MyHandleNoteOn functions.

Comment: You don't need to call `getData1()` because the `MyHandle` function already get this in their parameters. You are probably not using [volatile](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/20994/why-the-need-to-use-the-volatile-keyword-on-global-variables-when-handling-inter).

Comment: so i should use pitch instead of data1 ?

Comment: @CL. making that change had no effect.i think the while loop is blocking.dose it look like the while is the issue?